# Why won't QGIS show markers outside the window?

Tags: markers, visibility

I'm having an issue with the QGIS2.18.3: I have grid center points, where I want to put square shaped markers to create a grid. The problem is that if a center point is outside the window, the program won't draw the marker - leaving that part blank.

What would you suggest? Can I force somehow QGIS to draw everything despite it would not see it?

Comment: Please consider updating to the current LTR-version.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a specific then that is a strange way to create a grid. You could use the `Create Grid` tool in the Processing Toolbox which won't suffer from that issue.